# How to create dynamic dropdown linked in google Forms from sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to develop a link between google sheets and google forms to enter the relevant information. However I can create dependent dropdowns in google sheets, but I can't see how you can create a dynamically linked drop-down in google forms. Example is: 
Dropdown 1 = LIst of groups, for example, G1, G2
Once selected the drop-down 2 is prepopulated with the the people in G1 or G2 if selected. 
So G1 list has Ben, David and Phil
G2 list has Sarah, Claire and Karen

So if I selected G2 in Dropdown 1 I should get Sarah, Claire and Karen in the Dropdown 2 list to choose from.

However I need to have the dropdown 2 entries inserted in the same field in google sheets as if I had chosen G1 and then selected Ben, David or Phil.

Hope that is clear

Comment: To complement St3ph's answer, you can have [conditional sections](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en) in your Form, which can allow you to have some more control on the content depending on previous answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify on the fly a Google Forms, it is not possible by API, so changing dropdown 2 after user fill dropdown 1 is not possible.

Only things possible is to change drop down after a user submission for next submission like the add-on from ranger https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/form_ranger/387838027286 can do.

Stéphane